# How safe is it to create a second user account just to test potentially infected software?

Tags: windows-10

I have a windows 10 account with administrative privileges. I eventually need to download things that have a potential of having viruses on them, so to prevent them from reaching my account and files, I thought about creating another local restricted account so that if this account gets infected, I won't need to format the computer but just delete the account and its files. How likely is that to work, what are the risks and how to address them?

Comment: That will only work in some cases. A more reliable solution would be to use a virtual machine.

Comment: Extremely unsafe. A normal account downloading malicious software can still make your system unbootable.  Use a VM or a sandbox that isolated the program from your system.  Even those solutions are not 100% safe but safer then your idea

Comment: I agree with the other comments. In theory, a limited account can do less damage to the system, but if the malicious software is taking advantage of a vulnerability that results in an escalation of privilege, you're sunk. But then, some malware is aware that it is being executed in a VM and adjusts behavior to appear innocuous. You can't win. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just doing this in a virtual machine. You can use built in Hyper-V or something like VM Workstation Player for free. This would minimize the risk to your comupter.

Comment: A virtual machine does add a bit of protection, however, there are a couple of things to be aware of. It's possible for software to detect whether it's running on a virtual machine in several ways, including the presence of APIs specific to that VM and the combination of hardware the VM emulates. This means that malware might not do bad things if it's run within a VM. A more important concern is attacks designed to escape from a VM. While virtualization software is typically hardened, it's not immune to vulnerabilities, and, there have been some notable ones over the years.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above a VM would be a good choice.

As addition when using a Virtual Machine:

> Don't use Shared folders, disable it.
>
> Take a Snapshot of your clean vm to work on it.
>
> Don't use Bridged Mode as Network configuration, if you use network
>
> Don't use your regular account on your Host. To use the VM-Guest use a guest account which are restricted and maybe harden it.
>
> Not sure, but maybe use the VM in a second sandbox ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great idea.

It will work in many cases, but definitely not all.

Where malware takes advantage of an unpatched vulnerability it can bypass the user limits - and there are a number of known vulnerabilities - including (off the top of my head) the Wannacry - but there are plenty of others which don't require file sharing.  (Have a look [here](https://toshellandback.com/2015/11/24/ms-priv-esc/))

Another potential problem would be shared resources - for example if you have a shared public fileserver it could still delete files.

As @aMofo suggested, doing this kind of testing in a VM is a much safer idea.